# A word for a "cleaning schedule"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a (British) English word for a printed week-by-week cleaning schedule?

Comment: What is wrong with *cleaning schedule*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British house-shares this would normally be called a ***rota***:

> **rota** *noun*
>   **1** *British* a list showing when each of a number of people has to do a particular job:
>     *a cleaning rota*
>   Compare with *roster*.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rota?q=Rota)
>
> **roster** *noun*
>   a list or plan showing turns of duty or leave for individuals or groups in an organization:
>     *next week’s duty roster*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/roster)

Answer (score 0):

We might call it a *roster*: 'a list or plan showing the names of individuals or groups in any organization, frequently including the rotation of their duties.'